# wxwidget compiling on windows command prompt

Tags: c++, command, prompt, wxwidgets, msys

Can someone please guide me on the method,as to how I would compile wxwidget using windows command prompt or MSYS. [I can't seem to find anything on the wxwiki/wxwidget official book/anywhere else]

I have already compiled wxwidget from the instructions they have provided (using MSYS).

From searching on the Internet it seems one can (maybe?) do it through the use of MAKEFILE (is that correct?)

if yes: WHAT directory & HOW I should link the wx libraries in the MAKEFILE
if no: what is the way besides MAKEFILE?

I know I can use IDE's like code::block and make life simpler but I prefer to compile using the command prompt/msys.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which compiler?  The compiler is used to build wxWidgets.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: MINGW

Comment: Just for future reference to others: I found out how it is done through the Wxbook

Answer (score 0):

I have created a video on this topic https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6FDNR3lh8E
Here is small and simple steps to follow.

Pre-Requirements :

1. GNU g++ compiler downloaded and installed.
2. Set gcc/g++ path to Enviroment Variable.
3. Download WxWidgets Binaries : 1. Header Files, 2. Development Files, 3. DLLs.
4. Extract then one folder as it is. I have extracted them at D:\WxAPI Folder.
   Looks Like :
   D:
   - WxAPI Folder
   - include (Header files has this folder ziped in .7z)
   - lib (Development Files & DLL has this folder ziped in .7z and both extracts in this save folder)
5. Set your project development structure.

   My Project Development Structure :

   ```
    WxExample (Project Folder)
            - Build (Folder) : Contains debug and release dlls and exe
                - debug (Folder) : Contains debug specific dlls and exe.
                - release (Folder) : Contains release specific dlls and exe.
            - inlcude (Folder) : Contains project header files.
            - src (Folder) : Contains project .cpp files.
            - wxCompiler.cmd : Contains compile command created with following steps.
   ```

- Write Compilation Command

  - Link Following to Compile.

  1. First Compile Project *.cpp Files :
     g++ ".\src*.cpp"
  2. Give Project Output .exe Name :
     -o ".\build\release\Project_Name.exe"
  3. Show Project .h File Location to g++ :
     -I ".\include"
  4. Provide WxWidget .h Files :
     -I "D:\WxAPI\include"
  5. Locate WxWidget setup.h File :
     -I "D:\WxAPI\lib\gcc810_x64_dll\mswu"
  6. Supply Binaries Location of WxWidgets :
     -L "D:\WxAPI\lib\gcc810_x64_dll"
  7. Provide Compile Flags :
     -l wxbase31u
     -l wxmsw31u_core

  - Here D:\WxAPI\lib\gcc810_x64_dll\libwxbase31u.a File Renamed To "wxbase31u"
    & D:\WxAPI\lib\gcc810_x64_dll\libwxmsw31u_core.a File Renamed To "wxmsw31u_core" as flag.
  - You have to add similar file flag as you used in your project as .h
  - For Example :
    -lwxmsw31u_core  -lwxbase31u    -lwxtiff -lwxjpeg -lwxpng   -lwxzlib -lwxregexu -lwxexpat   -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -lwinspool -lwinmm -lshell32 -lshlwapi -lcomctl32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lrpcrt4 -ladvapi32 -lversion -lwsock32 -lwininet -loleacc -luxtheme
  - Here is Full Command :
    g++ ".\src*.cpp" -o ".\build\release" -I "D:\WxExample\include" -I "D:\WxAPI\include" -I "D:\WxAPI\lib\gcc810_x64_dll\mswu" -L "D:\WxAPI\lib\gcc810_x64_dll" -l wxbase31u -l wxmsw31u_core
  - Run wxWidgets.cmd and that's it. Your exe is in your .\Build\release folder.

  8. Set WxWidget DLL path in Enviroment Variable.
     If you do not want to copy paste required dll to your release/debug folder.